# dropping a database from php code

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to drop a database in php code.
In my application, I have following code.

```
$cmd = "mysql -h $host --port=$port -u $user -p$pass -e 'create database $database'";
$logger->log("running command '$cmd'");
exec($cmd, $output, $status);
```

when code is reached, it hangs and program never exists.
according the log command is correct.
that is log has following line.

```
running command 'mysql -h localhost --port=3306 -u root -p123 -e 'drop database my_test_db''
```

I copied the command and run it manually on the terminal. then it dropped the database within seconds.
Then I hard code the command in a simple php script and run. then also it dropped the database within seconds.

I can't figure out why it hangs in my application. can you please help me out.

Additional information: in the application, a connection is created to the same database and a transaction has started at the time this happens.

Comment: Why cant you do it the [normal](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) way? [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) can be very restrictive in almost any well configured servers.

Answer (score 0):

Is a better way create or drop database from a regular connection from php, instead of call external commands.

Function to create database
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-create-db.php

Function to drop database
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-drop-db.php